# Insert new column based on existing column in R

Tags: r

```
# Boundaries of new column 
boundaries <- c(
  as.Date(Sys.Date()) - 365,                 # < 1 year
  as.Date(Sys.Date()) - 2 * 365,             # > 1 year & < 2 years
  as.Date(Sys.Date()) - 3 * 365,             # < 2 years & < 3 years
  as.Date(Sys.Date()) - 5 * 365,             # > 3 years & < 5 years
  as.Date(Sys.Date()) - 5 * 365 - 1          # > 5 years
)

# add 'Date Category' 
df <- cbind(df, DateCategory = case_when(
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[1] ~ '< 1 year',
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[2] ~ '> 1 year & < 2 years',
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[3] ~ '< 2 years & < 3 years',
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[4] ~ '> 3 years & < 5 years',
  TRUE ~ '> 5 years'
))
```

I tried using this code to create a new column based on date values in de Date Ouverture column. But somehow this code is not working and returns only < 1 year. with these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">="
2: In eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">="
3: In eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">="
4: In eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">="
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `Sys.Date()` returns a `Date` class object, but from your warnings it looks like your data has a `POSIX` datetime object. The `cut` function will make this much easier. If you need more help than that, please post a few rows of sample data in a reproducible way so we can test solutions on your inputs.

Comment: (1) Sounds like `\`Date ouverture\`` is of class `POSIXt`, you can repeat that warning (and eventual mis-calc) with `Sys.time() > Sys.Date()`, which is akin to comparing `as.numeric(Sys.time())` (`1.69e+09`) with `as.numeric(Sys.Date())` (`19598`). You need to convert one of them, perhaps `boundaries <- as.POSIXt(boundaries)` after your initial declaration. (2) You're using `case_when` so you have `dplyr` loaded, I strongly suggest using `mutate` instead of `cbind`, something like `df <- mutate(df, DateCategory = case_when(...))` and _not_ using `df$` throughout that statement. More potential.

Comment: The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput` -- `dput(df[1:5, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `df`. If you have many irrelevant columns, you can select only the relevant ones with `dput(df[1:5, "Date ouverture", drop = FALSE])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that `` `Date ouverture` `` is of class `POSIXt`, not class `Date`. Note that since `>`-like comparisons are not configured for that comparison, it will likely convert each to numbers, where the `POSIXt` values will almost certainly always win:

```r
tm <- Sys.time()
dt <- Sys.Date()
tm > dt
# Warning: Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">"
# [1] TRUE
as.numeric(tm) > as.numeric(dt)
# [1] TRUE
as.numeric(tm)
# [1] 1.69e+09
as.numeric(dt)
# [1] 19598
```

I suggest you convert `boundaries` to be the former class:

```r
boundaries <- as.POSIX(boundaries)

### continuing my example above
dt <- as.POSIXct(dt)
as.numeric(dt)
# [1] 1.69e+09
```

so now the units are more comparable.

Side note: you're already using `dplyr` for `case_when`, I suggest:

- use `mutate` instead of `cbind`, and
- remove the `df$` references.

This provides more flexibility in the future, such as if you need to do grouping/window operations.

```r
boundaries <- as.POSIX(boundaries)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    DateCategory = case_when(
      `Date ouverture` >= boundaries[1] ~ '< 1 year',
      `Date ouverture` >= boundaries[2] ~ '> 1 year & < 2 years',
      `Date ouverture` >= boundaries[3] ~ '< 2 years & < 3 years',
      `Date ouverture` >= boundaries[4] ~ '> 3 years & < 5 years',
      TRUE ~ '> 5 years'
    )
  )
```

Though using GregorTHomas's suggestion for `cut`, this might be simplified to

```r
years <- c("< 1 year", "> 1 year & < 2 years", "< 2 years & < 3 years", "> 3 years & < 5 years", "> 5 years")
df %>%
  mutate(
    DateCategory = cut(`Date ouverture`, boundaries, labels = years)
  )
```

Comment: I'd also suggest that the boundaries can be set us with e.g. `lubridate::year` to more properly account for leap years etc. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I first tried:

```
boundaries <- as.POSIX(boundaries)
Error in as.POSIX(boundaries) : could not find function "as.POSIX"
```

Which did not work, changed it to:

```
boundaries <- as.POSIXct(boundaries)
```

Which lucky did not give any errors.

Whenever I tried using mutate this kept giving errors:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Even though I am completely sure there was no variable with the same name.

So fixed the code with using this instead:

```
boundaries <- as.POSIXct(boundaries)

# add 'Date Category' 
df <- cbind(df, DateCategory = case_when(
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[1] ~ '< 1 year',
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[2] ~ '> 1 year & < 2 years',
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[3] ~ '< 2 years & < 3 years',
  df$`Date ouverture` >= boundaries[4] ~ '> 3 years & < 5 years',
  TRUE ~ '> 5 years'
))
```

And now everything seems fine!

Thanks for the help!